# Multiple y-Axis in CorePlot

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-plot

What I'm trying to accomplish with CorePlot on the iPhone is to plot two graphs in two different PlotSpaces. The y-Axis of the first PlotSpace should appear on the left and the y-Axis of the second one on the right.

The documentation gives a hint that it should be possible but I have no idea how to accomplish it.

I tried the following but failed miserably:

```
 CPXYAxis *leftY = [[[CPXYAxis alloc] init] autorelease];
 CPXYAxis *rightY = [[[CPXYAxis alloc] init] autorelease];
 CPXYAxis *x = [[[CPXYAxis alloc] init] autorelease];

 CPAxisSet *axisSet = [[[CPAxisSet alloc] init] autorelease];
 axisSet.axes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:x,leftY,rightY,nil];
 graph.axisSet = axisSet;

 leftY.plotSpace = leftAxisPlotSpace;
 rightY.plotSpace = rightAxisPlotSpace;
 x.plotSpace = rightAxisPlotSpace;
```

All I get are 3 x-Axis.

Any idea how I could accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify which are the y-axes:

```
leftY.coordinate = CPCoordinateY;
rightY.coordinate = CPCoordinateY;
```